# Formula to calculate the sum of timecodes - AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, video, script

After extensive research on the Internet I could't find a decent formula to calculate (add) timecodes, so I'm building my own script from scratch.

So far I can get a pretty decent result, however I'm having trouble to account for Drop-Frame timelines. According from what I learned, they jump from frame 29 to 02, unless its the 10th (or multiples) minute, in which case the 00 and 01 frames will be there.

**Any advice on how to implement this feature?**

Also any improvement to the script will be welcome.

```
global tcSTART
global tcDURATION
global tcFINAL
global frameRATE

on run
    set frameRATE to "23.98" -- test frame rate
    set tcSTART to "04:03:02:01" -- test Value 1
    set tcDURATION to "01:02:03:04" -- teste Value 2

    my calcFinalTC()
    display dialog tcFINAL
end run

on calcFinalTC()
    set FF to (word 4 of tcSTART) + (word 4 of tcDURATION)
    set SS to (word 3 of tcSTART) + (word 3 of tcDURATION)
    set MM to (word 2 of tcSTART) + (word 2 of tcDURATION)
    set HH to (word 1 of tcSTART) + (word 1 of tcDURATION)
    if FF ≥ frameRATE then
        set FF to (FF - (round (frameRATE)))
        set SS to (SS + 1)
    end if
    if SS ≥ 60 then
        set SS to (SS - 60)
        set MM to (MM + 1)
    end if
    if MM ≥ 60 then
        set MM to (MM - 60)
        set HH to (HH + 1)
    end if
    if HH > 23 then
        display dialog "The timeline can't be larger than 24 hours" buttons {"OK"}
        error -128
    end if
    if the length of ((FF div 1) as string) = 1 then
        set FF to "0" & FF
    end if
    if the length of ((SS div 1) as string) = 1 then
        set SS to "0" & SS
    end if
    if the length of ((MM div 1) as string) = 1 then
        set MM to "0" & MM
    end if
    if the length of ((HH div 1) as string) = 1 then
        set HH to "0" & HH
    end if
    set tcFINAL to HH & ":" & MM & ":" & SS & ":" & FF
end calcFinalTC
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, when you say *"After extensive research on the Internet I could't find a decent formula to calculate (add) timecodes"*, in what software were you originally wanting to use the formula in? Also, can you provide some context around what you're wanting to do overall (just because it may help inform any answers you get).

Comment: @Monomeeth I'm building a script using Automator to read several lines with timecodes (TC IN and DURATION) from an Excel document (in fact a tabbed TXT exported from Final Cut Pro), figure out the TC OUT and fill a PDF report. Although there are some sites with timecode calculators none of them provide the actual formula that was used so I can adapt to my needs.

Comment: The script above works fine with 23.98, 24, 25, 30 and 60 fps but not with 29.97 drop frame.

Comment: Can you explain what a timecode is in your particular situation ?  Is it the representation `hh:mm:ss` to stand for `hh` number of hours + `mm` number of minutes + `ss` number of seconds ?  And these are relative timecodes rather than absolute values referenced by a fixed point in time ?  What does `23.98` represent ?

Comment: @CJK I work with many movies at different frame rates. Most of the time they are 24 fps or 23.98 fps. HH:MM:SS:FF stands for hours, minutes, seconds and frames. That means after 24 frames 1 second is added under that frame rate. 00:00:01:23 --> 00:00:02:00. Under 30 fps that would be 00:00:01:29 --> 00:00:02:00. Note that timecode does not always mean real time, it is actually a label for every frame when the camera is recording. They are always recorded one after another no matter what. Problem is back in the day USA went from Black and White to Color using the same hardware... (continue)

Comment: ...so to add the color information to the NTSC tape they "drop" a little bit of info every second. That means 2 frames every minute. NTSC is always 29.97 fps. So the frame rate goes normal but it jumps from 00:00:59:29 to 00:01:00:02. Two frames are gone like magic. That is true unless its the 10th minute (or 20, 30, 40, 50). That means 00:09:59:29 --> 00:10:00:00. So after 1 hour of tape the real clock will be 1 hour late as well. For 23.98 fps that rule does not apply. The frames are recorded in a logical sequence. For counting purposes, 23.98 fps = 24 fps. Its just a technical difference.

Comment: That's the reason of the "round" in the code. The 29.97 fps is in fact 30 fps for basically every 59 seconds and 10th multiples. In other words, 18 frames (9 minutes x2 frames) are dropped for every 10 minutes.